# How to make a graphql client in Apollo?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have built a `graphql` server in `apollo-server-express`. I can use `apollo playground` to send request and get response. The request I send in the playground is

```
{
  query: me {username}
}
```

and I can get the expected response on the right panel. But I get some troubles to build a client with `apollo-client`. Below is the source code:

```
const gql = require('graphql-tag');
const ApolloClient = require('apollo-boost').default;
const fetch = require('node-fetch').default;

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql',
  fetch
});

client
  .query({
    query: gql`
      query me {
        username
      }
    `
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

I get `400` error response when run the above code. Below is the full error message. I am new to graphql and what's wrong with my code?

```
name: 'ServerError',
     response:
      Response {
        size: 0,
        timeout: 0,
        [Symbol(Body internals)]: [Object],
        [Symbol(Response internals)]: [Object] },
     statusCode: 400,
     result: { errors: [Array] } },
  message:
   'Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400',
```

If I change the query to `query : me {` I will get this error: `raphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected {, found : at syntaxError ...`

The server code is:

```
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express');

const app = express();

const schema = gql`
  type Query {
    me: User
  }

  type User {
    username: String!
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    me: () => {
      return {
        username: 'Robin Wieruch'
      };
    }
  }
};
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: schema,
  resolvers,
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' });


app.listen({ port: 8000 }, () => {
  console.log('Apollo Server on http://localhost:8000/graphql');
});
```

Comment: `query me {` vs `query : me {`

Comment: I get this error when run `query : me {`: ` raphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected {, found :`

Comment: wrap all the query within `{   }`, you can also try `{ me {` alone

Comment: yep, `{ }` wrapper works.

Comment: Why are you giving fetch into the ApolloClient? In the docs they used a cache and the uri: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/client/#make-your-first-query

Comment: Because I am using `nodejs` which doesn't have fetch.